# Finding a value of a series using z-transform

Tags: z-transform

Having the z-transform formula:
\begin{equation}
    V(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x_nz^{-n}
\end{equation}

I want to find the value of the series

\begin{equation}
    \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n}{3^n}
\end{equation}

we have that $z=3$ and $x_n=n$, using the table of transforms we have:

\begin{equation}
    \begin{array}{cc}
         n=\frac{z}{(z-1)^2}  \\
         3^n=\frac{z}{z-3} 
    \end{array}
\end{equation}

thus the z-transform of the series is:
\begin{equation}
  x(z)= \frac{z}{(z-1)^2}\frac{z}{z-3}
\end{equation}

But how do I find the value of that series with this z-transform?

I tried using integration from $0$ to infinity, but that didn't give any convergent value.

How do I find that value of the series?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to transform $3^n$.

You have that $V(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty nz^{-n}$, and you are looking for $V(3)$.

The "table of transform" gives you that $V(z) = \frac{z}{(z-1)^2}$. Can you continue from here?

Comment: Yes, I can, I just insert for z=3 in  the given  transform. But why do you have only one term, why no need to transform 3^n? The solution would be $V(3)=\frac{3}{2^2}=\frac{3}{4}$.

Comment: I am not sure which source you are using, but read carefully how the "table of transform" is meant to be used. Specifically, $\sum_{n=0}^\infty n3^{-n}$ is $\sum_{n=0}^\infty nz^{-n}$ evaluated at $z=3$. Now find a closed form for $\sum_{n=0}^\infty nz^{-n}$ using the "table of transform" (notice there is no $3^{-n}$ here). Finally evaluate it at $z=3$ and you're done.

Comment: The table says  $a^n=\frac{z}{z-a}$ and $n=\frac{z}{(z-1)^2}$. So for a=3, it is clear. For n, it is also clear. If I plug in for 3 in the former, I get a non-existing singularity, while for the latter, I get that answer given above.

Comment: Also be careful that the transform of a product is **not** always (and rarely) the product of the transforms. For instance $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{-n} =\sum_{n=0}^\infty 1z^{-n}= z/(z-1)= \sum_{n=0}^\infty 1\times 1 z^{-n} \ne (\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{-n})\times (\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{-n})= z^2/(z-1)^2\,.$$

Comment: Sure, that counts as well for Laplace transforms, and Fourier transforms. Thanks